# How to execute a jar that uses another jar

Tags: java, android, jar

I have a little problem importing a project to my android project.

I have built a little library using Ical4Java to parse a .ical file, and that library is exported to a .jar.

In my Android Project i have imported and added to the build path my generated .jar from my library that includes some jars to make my library work.

But when i run my application it just crashes and i get this on the LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14382): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarBuilder
```

That library (ical4j.jar) is imported on the library buildpath and is exported whith my library (mylibrary.jar)..

Answer (score 2):

You can use [One-Jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/one-jar/) to help you use a jar file that is dependent on other jar files. Basically you can combine them into one jar file.

Here is a little [tutorial](http://beautifulwaste.blogspot.com/2007/06/running-jar-file-that-includes-another.html) to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Is `mylibrary.jar` an executable jar file?

If so, you cannot reference external jars.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the content of the one jar into the other jar (combine them). They are just zip files.

Comment: hmm

Extract the content of all the 17 .jar files and just put them on "mylibrary.jar" ?

Comment: @rafuru: Yes, if you're using Eclipse, it will do this for you when you use the Export To Jar (I think that's what it's called) feature.

Comment: Yeah, in my library project i use Export-> jar file ...

and also includes all jars used, but on android i recive that NoClassDefFoundError..

Comment: @rafuru Does the exported jar contain net/fortuna/ical4j/data/CalendarBuilder.class? If not, it doesn't include all jars used.

Comment: perhaps you just need to add this dependency in Eclipse, so that it knows to copy it in